# Sending an SMS via sms gateway in delphi

Tags: delphi, http-post, delphi-xe2, sms-gateway

the code "supplied" by the gateway website is available at http://www.freesmsgateway.com/api
I did my best in terms of trying to implement this but have no idea. Googled extensively to no avail. This is something quite cool to implement into a program so i hope a detailed answer would be able to help many people. It appears to post so maybe i interpreted the parameters wrong? Any help or input is valued. Please excuse any formatting mishaps? first time poster to the site. Btw using delphi XE4. message output is in the link below [showmessage returned text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM4r3.png).

Here is the delphi code:

```
function tform1.PostExample: string;
     var    param:TStringList;
            valid:boolean;
            url,text:string;
            http:TIDHttp;
      begin
         http := TIDHttp.Create(nil);
         http.HandleRedirects := true;
         http.ReadTimeout := 5000;
         param:=TStringList.create;
         param.Clear;
         param.Add('access_token=994ad8885430************91b6eb8f');
         param.Add('message=Test');
         param.Add('send_to=0729122723');
         valid:=true;
         url:='http://www.FreeSMSGateway.com/api_send';
          try
            text:=http.Post(url,param);
          except
           on E:Exception do
            begin
             valid:=false;
            end;
          end;
         if valid then
          showmessage( text )
          else
          showmessage( '' );
         end;
         end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentatation](http://www.freesmsgateway.com/api) again more carefully:

> Send a POST call to http://www.FreeSMSGateway.com/api_send with the following POST variables:
>
> - access_token: Your API Access Token from your account dashboard
>
>   message: The url encoded message, 160 characters or less
>
>   **send_to: This value need to be "existing_contacts" to send to all your existing contacts in your account or "post_contacts" to supply a custom list of contacts**
>
>   **post_contacts: A JSON array of contacts to send the message to instead of your existing contacts. Only required is "send_to" is set to "post_contacts"**

Your `send_to` param value does not meet the requirements stated.  You are passing the specific contact number in the `send_to` field, but that contact must be passed in the `post_contacts` field instead, eg:

```
param.Add('access_token=994ad8885430************91b6eb8f');
param.Add('message=Test');
//param.Add('send_to=0729122723');
param.Add('send_to=post_contacts');
param.Add('post_contacts=["0729122723"]'); // you may need to double-check this syntax
```